# Calibrate without a known good voltage source

Tags: voltage, voltage-reference, calibration

I'm traveling and don't have a known exact voltage source. I do have a variety of electronic components such as resistors of various flavors and am wondering if there is some kind of trick to getting a known voltage value against which I could calibrate a DMM ( which would in turn allow me to calibtate all sorts of other stuff).

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Which voltage is required? And how about a voltage regulator?

Comment: I'm interested in voltages in the 2V up to 12V range. I have a few voltage regulators kicking around, but I don't have any way to know which are accurate! For example, the 5V regulated output from my computers USB port seems to be as much as 10% lower than 5V.

Comment: Why not just borrow a DMM that is known to work, measure something and then you have your reference?

Comment: Partly because I'm traveling and don't know where to find such a DMM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're serious, somewhere down the line you're going to have to buy - or build - something which is more accurate than the device you're calibrating/testing.

If it were me, I'd build, and I'd use an array of Zeners - [**LM4040s**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4040-n.pdf) - rather than a single reference and a voltage divider to get various output voltages from - let's call it - the voltage calibrator.  That way, there's only a single non-precision current limiting resistor required between the raw supply and each Zener's cathode, and the inherent accuracy of each Zener's output voltage will be maintained since it won't be compromised by the tolerance of the voltage divider's resistor chain.

There are 6 individual output voltages available from LM4040s: 2.5V, 3V, 4.096V, 5V, 8.192V, and 10 volts, and they're all wired as shunt regulators, like this,
[image]

where the value of Rs is determined by Ohm's law and is:

$$ R_{S} = \frac{V_{DD} - V_{OUT}}{I_Z} $$

The LM4040 exhibits a very stable Vout for a very wide range of Iz, so for an LM4040-10 with a Vdd of 12V and an Iz of 1 milliampere, Rs would be:

$$ R_{S} = \frac{12V - 10V}{0.001A} = 2000 \text { ohms}  $$

It's important to realize that current taken by the load connected between Vout and ground will cause the current through the Zener to be decreased by that amount, but with high-resistance loads, (voltmeters and such) that change in current through the Zener should have only a miniscule effect on Vout.

Finally, checking [**DigiKey**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-reference/2556223?k=LM4040&pv1779=33&FV=fff40027%2Cfff8013f%2Cc0172&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) for prices yields USD 1.78 for a 10 volt +/- 0.1% unit, which is pretty close to dirt cheap, so putting together an array of all six Zeners certainly won't break the bank, especially since the current limiting resistors can all be vanilla 5% carbon films.

Comment: Thanks - and I was serious. I see if I can get ahold of any LM4040s easily. The idea was hopefully to calibrate with what I have lying around (of course, it's tough to list everything), but these are all great suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome; my pleasure. **:)** If you like my answer and nothing better pops up in the next few days, I'd appreciate an accept.

Answer (score 3):

If all you've got is resistors, that's not going to go so well. Resistors are great at being linear devices. Voltage references (of the two terminal flavour) are very *nonlinear* devices (voltage is constant irrespective of current).

If you've got any sort of semiconductor device, you could try and use a diode drop as a voltage reference. But diodes aren't all that great, and different types/models have different voltage drops. A Zener would be nice, but if you don't have a voltage regulator, I'm going to assume you don't have a Zener lying around.

If you have zinc, zinc sulfate, mercury, and mercurous sulfate, you could build a [Clark cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark_cell), which provides a relatively constant 1.434V. However, this requires fancy glass ware, platinum wires, and, well, *mercury*. An alternative (with considerably better tempco) is the [Weston cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weston_cell); again, this requires mercury and *cadmium sulfate octahydrate*, among other things. I haven't the slightest idea what that is, but it sounds scary.

---

In your comment, you mentioned that you some regulators lying around. These are by far your best bet. The usefulness will depend greatly on the type of regulator, but if you have something like an LM317 regulator, the reference voltage will be 1.25V nominally, +/- 50mV. A generic fixed linear regulator like a 7805 has about the same precision (4.8-5.2V), but if you have more precise regulators, those could be better.

Another trick would be to rip open a piece of equipment you own that has an internal voltage reference.

Perhaps the real question is, what's wrong with your DMM? Any half-decent DMM should be accurate enough for a lot of tasks. I mean, even those $7 meters they hand out for free at Harbor Freight claim an accuracy of ~1%.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I have any bare regulators lying around, but I have a few chips that have integrated regulators, and some boards (e.g., an arduino) that have regulators on board. So maybe I can hijack one of those.

Comment: To answer your question about the DMMs - it's partly because I don't really trust those 1% figures, but also because in my application I'm dealing with automotive lead acid voltages (~12V) where the voltage range from fully charged to discharged is less than 1V, so accuracy of 1% (0.12V) can imply an error in estimating SoC of more than 10%.

Comment: Lead acid state of charge - measure the specific gravity of the electrolyte - cheap, small, accurate tools for this are available in most any auto parts store.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage regulator voltage references: TL431 or TLV431 are moderately decent for limited value of moderate (1.5% unless they are the higher-bin versions up to 0.5%... LM317 likewise has a low-volt reference built in.

If the DMM is worth owning, it will be better than that without fussing. If it's not better than that without fussing, it's not worth dragging with you while traveling.

Expecting USB power to be worth anything as a reference is just plain silly.

Comment: Well I need a DMM since I'm on an extended trip and certainly can't work on much without such a basic tool. Unfortunately, "a DMM worth owning" often equates to an expensive instrument like a fluke which I can't afford at the moment. So I'm looking to calibrate the cheap instrument(s) that I do have.

Answer (score 1):

A USB port in a computer should be between 5.0 and 5.1V; if that precision fits you.
A healthy automotive battery that has rested overnight should be around 12.6 to 12.8V; if that precision fits you.
Inside a PC, there is a 3.3 Volt rail that should be less than +/- 0.1V, if that precision fits you.
A LED will show a steady voltage across depending on its color.

Answer (score 1):

AA, C, D cells are available everywhere.  Their voltage is ~1.54V new.
Several in series will give decent accurate voltage steps for calibration using, 1 , 2 , 3 , 4... of them.

Comment: Good budget approach :)